# how to copy data from one table to other in arcpy where the name of fields are different?

Tags: python, merge, arcpy

There are two tables of different feature class, say `Source` and `Target`, the fields in both the table are not same and even the number of fields are different.

- There are 5 different fields that need to be copied from `Source` to `Target`(name of each field is different)
- Field names are, -`UUID` in `Source` table which is similar to `NE_UUID` in `Target` table
- `date_of_Modification` in `Source` table which is similar to `NE_date_of_modification` in `Target` table

and so on for rest of 3 fields.

The catch is, if `UUID`(source) is not present in `NE_UUID`(target) it should insert the entire row of 5 fields to target table.

Is there a function/method in arcpy which can do this, or do I need to use cursor for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found a way.

```
curS2=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(target,"NE_UUID")
curS3=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(source,source_list)
curI=arcpy.da.InsertCursor(target, target_list)

curS_list=[y[0] for y in curS2]


print ("loading list.....")

for x in curS3:
    if not x[0] in curS_list:
        curI.insertRow(x)



del curI,curS2,curS3
```